# Build Tomcat using local OpenSSL 1.0.2 on RedHat

Tags: openssl, redhat, tomcat8

I'm trying to compile Tomcat 1.2 with SSL on RedHat 7. Since RedHat does not ship OpenSSL 1.0.2, I downloaded OpenSSL 1.0.2j and compile it. The install location is `/usr/local/ssl`. I tried to pass that path to the configure script using `./configure --with-ssl==/usr/local/ssl --with-apr=/usr/bin/apr-1-config --with-java-home=/usr/java/default` but I kept getting the following error message:

```
checking for OpenSSL library... using openssl from /usr/lib and /usr/include
checking OpenSSL library version >= 1.0.2...

Found   OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER 0x1000105f (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013)
Require OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER 0x1000200f or greater (1.0.2)

configure: error: Your version of OpenSSL is not compatible with this version of tcnative
```

When I do a "openssl version", it says I'm running OpenSSL 1.0.2j.

Comment: update your OpenSSL.

Comment: 1.0.1e is the latest for RHEL7. Which is why I installed 1.0.2j.

Comment: The double equal sign may be a problem: `--with-ssl==/usr/local/ssl`. Maybe you can try a single equal sign. Otherwise, we need to see the details of the relevant tests from `config.log`. [Apache Tomcat SSL/TLS Configuration HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) may be helpful, too.

Comment: @jww Yea, that was the issue. Removing the extra "=" and the configure script picked up the right OpenSSL version. Thanks!